# Can't Execvp " No such File or Directory " Error in geany Editor

Tags: command-line, geany

I am getting this error in Geany Editor while executing a simple program:

```
Can't Execvp " No such File or Directory "
```

I want to set `xterm` as Geany Terminal Emulator. But I think I've accidentally screwed up my shell path.

Can Anybody Provide me with the default shell path of Geany.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get shell path corrected, go to `Edit > Preferences > Terminal > Shell:` and set that to whatever shell you use. For example `/bin/bash`.

By default the shell path is `/bin/bash`.